# Empty request.POST after upgrade to Django 1.3

Tags: python, django, http-post

The following code works fine under Django 1.2 but fails under Django 1.3 because request.POST is empty, although the form data is posted correctly to the server

```
def commit_form(request):
    logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ": commit data " + request.raw_post_data)
    purchase = Purchase.objects.get(transaction_id=request.POST['TransactionID']) #breaks here, request.POST is empty

    #other stuff...

    return HttpResponse("GOOD", mimetype="text/plain")
```

Why does this not work, I can't see any error here?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will fix your problem, but you should in any case do `transaction_id=request.POST.get('TransactionID', None)`

Comment: is the `request.raw_post_data` empty, did you try using django-debug-toolbar?

Comment: Please provide traceback if any.

Comment: no request.raw_post_data is not empty, it contains the correct form data

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: I have the solution now, unfortunately I can't answer my own question for some hours. But it is a very interesting answer, it has to do with how django handels POST, which seems to have changed between 1.2 and 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall having a problem of this kind, it turned out that accessing `request.raw_post_data` prevented the `request.POST` dict from being subsequently populated with the post params. What happens if you remove the logging.debug line?

Comment: right, that was the problem, it works when you access request.POST before request.raw_post_data. In Django 1.2 this doesn't matter in 1.3 it matters

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (empty request.POST) with django 1.3, but it was due to a bug in my HTML.

I had a form with `action="foo"` but my urls.py mapped "foo/" to the view (where I was expecting some POST data, and getting none). Django kindly server-side redirects requests for "foo" to "foo/", but the POST data was not being resubmitted to "foo/" as part of the deal. In hindsight that seems quite sensible. Changing my form (to `action="foo/"`) fixed it, I suppose changing the urls.py could have worked too.

Comment: Awesome, this helped me out. I had an AJAX call going to '/new_player' and the urls.py was redirecting to '/new_player/' and running the view that was for '/new_player/' but the POST/GET data was lost between the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Also check your content type header.

Eg.

```
'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

Earlier versions were more accommodating if this header was missing or invalid.