# Empty request.POST in a Django view

Tags: python, django, post

When sending a POST request to the following view, the `request.POST` dictionary is empty:

```
@csrf_exempt
def created_query(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=request.POST['server'])
        if server.owner == request.user:
            if server.created:
                return HttpResponse("created")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("pending")
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden
```

I have tried with multiple ways of generating the POST request such as this cURL request:

```
curl --request POST \
--url http://localhost:80/created/ \
--form server=60 \
--form action=created
```

I have checked the dictionary using a debugger as well as just printing it and it is always empty. I doubt it is a problem with the `urls.py` however here is the line in the file that handles this view:

```
url(r'^created/', views.created_query, name='created'),
```

Things we've already tried:

- [Checking request content type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912627/3832377)
- [Checking for use of raw_post_data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7446387/3832377)

Comment: what is supposed to be posted? I can't see a form being created

Comment: This isn't being sent via a form, it's actually an API endpoint which takes two items in the body, server & action (as can be seen from the CURL request).  Neither of these are present in the final request.POST however, @Hisagr

Comment: yes `request.body` will work surely in case of facebook webhook.

Answer (score 4):

Starting at Django 1.5, POST does not contain non-form data anymore.

You can use `request.body`.

Comment: Is there any information on `request.post` on the Django documentation?  I can see a lot for `POST`, but Google doesn't do well with lower case vs. upper case.

Comment: well, if you are only use django, you can use `request.body`. And request.post only use in django rest framework. Here is [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.5/#non-form-data-in-http-requests)